# Joomla PHP elseif redirecting page back to itself

Tags: php, joomla

I can't figure out how to get a page to let it's links be clicked without redirecting to itself due to some php code that keeps redirecting it to itself.

```
$option = $_GET[option];
$view = $_GET[view];

if (!$option) {
    include "include/index_main.php"; // INDEX MAIN TOP FILE
} 
elseif ($option == 'com_newsfeeds' and $view == 'newsfeed') {
    include "include/news.php"; // NEWS FILE
} 
elseif ($option == 'com_content' and $view == 'category') {
    switch($_GET[id]) {
        case '75':
            include "include/children_list.php"; // Children List FILE
            break;
        case '77':
            include "include/food_for_kids.php"; // Food 4 Kids page
            break;
        case '76':
            include "include/water_for_life.php"; // Water for Life page
            break;
        default:
            if (empty($_GET[listing_id]) || $_GET[listing_id] == '') {
                include "include/projects.php"; // Projects FILE
                break;  
            }
            else {
                include "include/project_list.php"; // Project Listing FILE 
                break;
            }
    }   
}
elseif... ... ...
```

This works great when the page doesn't have any links to it's own category, but the maps with the markers all have links that seem to be redirected back on to the page instead of where they're supposed to go.

The problem lies in the *case '76':* portion

As far as I can tell, when the category id is 76, the php calls up the water_for_life.php include. Unfortunately, it doesn't make a distinction between:

```
.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=76
```

and

```
.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=76&listing_id=76&sid=dl94q3tlfqr2s58c3u1mfnf1t1
```

So after all that, I guess my question is:

**Is there a way to skip it all the way to the** include/project_list.php
 **once someone clicks on the link that has a link like this:**

```
.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=76&listing_id=76&sid=dl94q3tlfqr2s58c3u1mfnf1t1
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this? Note it apply to all cases irelevant of the id, whether it's 76 or 77 or whatever

```
...
elseif ($option == 'com_content' and $view == 'category') {
if (!empty($_GET['listing_id'])) {
    include "include/project_list.php"; // Project Listing FILE 
}
else {
  switch($_GET['id']) {
    case '75':
        include "include/children_list.php"; // Children List FILE
        break;
    case '77':
        include "include/food_for_kids.php"; // Food 4 Kids page
        break;
    case '76':
        include "include/water_for_life.php"; // Water for Life page
        break;
    default:
        include "include/projects.php"; // Projects FILE
        break;  
    } 
}
...
```

Comment: You sir, are amazing @Marko. Thank you!

I'm a total novice at this, but getting to know and learn more.

I wish I could upvote that, I will once I get enough rep.